# Haskell Maybe list element operations

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'm learning list operations in Haskell and now I'm trying out various list operations on Maybe list type. Currently, I have this implementation of sum of elements in list in Haskell

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum [] = 0
sum (a:t) = a + sum t
```

Now I want to do the same thing but instead of returning the value, I want to return a Maybe type instead. And when the list given is empty it should return Nothing.

I've come up with this

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> Maybe a
sum [] = Nothing
sum (a:t) = fmap (a+) (sum t)
```

But the result of all non empty list given results in Nothing.

From what I understand, the list given will eventually pattern match with the empty list therefore returning Nothing.

How do I fix this so that it returns the expected value and of Maybe type. I can't figure out how to make it work recursively as the normal sum implementation above, so I guess there should be another way. Would prefer if only Prelude module is imported as I'm still trying to absorb stuff inside the Prelude module.

Comment: Note that the correct sum of an empty list is 0, so your sum function is actually wrong. It doesn't not exist - it's 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your recursive function *always* uses the empty list as a base case, so your base case value is *always* `Nothing`. You only want to return `Nothing` if the "root" call takes an empty list. Otherwise, you want to use the singleton list as your base case.

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> Maybe a
sum [] = Nothing
sum [x] = Just x
sum (a:t) = fmap (a+) (sum t)
```

This way, `sum []` will never be reached by a recursive call; any non-empty list will hit the base case `sum [x]` first.

Another way to organize this is to use your original total function as a helper that sums non-empty lists only, and handle the empty list separately.

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> Maybe a
sum [] = Nothing
sum xs = sum' xs
  where sum' [] = Just 0
        sum' (a:t) = fmap (a+) (sum' t)
```

Note that `sum'` can be called on an empty list, but *only* if it is originally called on a non-empty list.

As @chi points out, the helper function doesn't need to use `Maybe` at all; since it only sums non-empty lists, you can skip using `fmap` and sum the list normally; only the final result needs to be wrapped in `Just`:

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> Maybe a
sum [] = Nothing
sum xs = Just (sum' xs)
         where sum' [] = 0
               sum' (a:t) = a + sum' t
```

Comment: In the last example we can also lift `Just` outside the recursion as in `sum [] = Nothing ; sum xs = Just (sum' xs)` where `sum' [] = 0 ; sum' (a:t) = a + sum' t`. This avoids `fmap`, so it perhaps less useful as a teaching exercise.

Comment: @chi That's probably actually clearer, as it emphasizes that the `Maybe` wrapper only applies to the final sum of a non-empty original argument.